# Can the Goldbach Conjecture be an impossible-to-prove statement, if true?

Tags: logic

From the paper "*Sentences undecidable in Peano Arithmetic whose truth values are unknown*" [Kreisel] (http://www.philosophy.ox.ac.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0013/1192/Incompletness.pdf), it's hard to escape the question of whether or not there's any statement about the natural numbers that it's impossible to know its truth value, **even in principle**. Thus the question above about the Goldbach Conjecture.

Answer (score 4):

In principle, yes - we currently know no reason to believe that the Goldbach conjecture must be decidable in $PA$ (or $ZFC$, say), although I think most mathematicians believe this would be very unlikely.

Note, however, that if Goldbach is *false*, then it is *disprovable*. A counterexample to Goldbach can be "verified in finite time" - if you give me an even integer $n$, I can check all the pairs of primes $<n$ to see if they add up to $n$. In fact, $PA$ can prove that, if $PA$ does not disprove Goldbach, then Goldbach is true! :P So if I can prove "Goldbach is unrpovable in PA" in some theory $T$ (say, ZFC), and I'm confident that $T$ is consistent, then I'm confident that Goldbach is true.

This is not true in general. For instance, a counterexample to the Twin Prime Conjecture is some $n$ such that there are no twin primes $>n$. In principle, this is *not* verifiable in finite time (as far as we know)! This difference is captured in the syntactic structure of each conjecture: Goldbach is $\Pi^0_1$, but Twin Primes is $\Pi^0_2$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy, and also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569906/is-there-a-statement-which-require-an-infinite-computation-to-check-independent/1569972#1569972.

Comment: Imho, however, "_we currently know no reason to believe that the Goldbach conjecture must be decidable in PA (or ZFC, say)_" is, in the name of rigorous logical reasoning, not the requested meta level proof demonstrating the impossibility to prove the conjecture being true (assuming it is so).

Comment: @NamNguyen Indeed, my point was that currently no proof of undecidability or decidability - or anything remotely approaching such a proof; even a plausible reason! - is known. So the best that can be said in response to your question, at the current time, is: it is, as far as we know, possible that Goldbach is undecidable in PA; and it is possible, as far as we know, that Goldbach is decidable in PA.

Comment: Note that we can't hope for much more, without solving Goldbach. Suppose I prove in (say) ZFC that it is consistent with (say) PA that Goldbach is true but undecidable in PA. Then in ZFC, I've proved that Goldbach is true, since otherwise Goldbach would be disprovable in PA. So without solving Goldbach, all we can do is talk about possible behavior of sentences of arithmetic which are "similar" to Goldbach: in particular, there are true $\Pi^0_1$ sentences which are true but unprovable.

Comment: (By contrast, if I proved (in ZFC) that the Twin Primes Conjecture is undecidable in PA, ZFC still might not know anything about the truth of TPC. This is the crucial difference between $\Pi^0_1$ statements and $\Pi^0_2$ (or worse) statements.)

Comment: Also, I'm challenging the notion that if the Goldbach Conjecture is false we could show that in finite number of steps. (We're assuming the set of natural numbers is countable, while there are lurking statements about the natural numbers that it might be impossible to verify).

Consider the distinct possibility that there are exactly two counter examples of the conjecture, can we demonstrate, e.g., the maximum counter example is a multiple of 5, when, as it stands right now, it might indeed be impossible to verify even in principle there being exactly two counter examples (even if true)?

Comment: @NamNguyen None of that affects the fact that showing that Goldbach is undecidable in PA amounts to showing that Goldbach is true. All we need is one counterexample. If there are only two counterexamples to Goldbach (say), there is indeed no reason we could prove that; but we could verify that each counterexample *is* a counterexample, and all we need is one to disprove Goldbach.

Comment: And I do not understand your statement "We're assuming the set of natural numbers is countable" - it's countable by definition! (Or are you talking about the set of natural numbers *relative to some model*? in which case this doesn't matter - the true natural numbers are an initial segment of any model of PA) We're mixing semantic ("the natural numbers", "true") and syntactic ("PA proves") concepts here, so it's easy to devolve into philosophical disagreements, but let's start with a basic result: PA proves "If Goldbach is false, then PA proves that Goldbach is false." This is a good exercise.

Comment: (An aside: Lob's Theorem states that, if PA were to prove "If PA proves Goldbach, then Goldbach is true," then PA would prove Goldbach! But that's sort of the dual to what's going on here.)

Comment: @Noah Schweber You mentioned "_it's countable by definition!_": so it depends on **which definition** we've chosen.

We can have the below definition of infinite-countability, assuming we take for granted these notions, given a set S: finite(S), PowerSet(S), subset(S), cardinality(S).

uncountable(S) <=> neg(finite(S)) and (There exists S' = subset(S), where S =/= S' and neg(finite(S') and cardinality(S) = cardinality(PowerSet(S'))).<br/>

countable(S)   <=> finite(S) or (neg(finite(S) and neg(uncountable(S))).

Comment: @NamNguyen Your "definition" is **incorrect**: for instance, it is consistent that $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_1$, so by your definition $\aleph_1$ would be countable. The definition of countable is "in bijection with a subset of the natural numbers." The **only** caveat here is that some authors use "countable" to mean "countable *and infinite*," but this is a red herring in this context. If you are going to use mathematical terms, use them the way they are defined; this is very silly. And, I **still have no idea** what this has to do with my answer!

Comment: @Noah Schweber So, the set of the natural numbers is countable because basically the set of the natural numbers is countable - by definition! That sounds like a circularity-definition, imho.

Comment: @NamNguyen Too bad. "Countable" is just shorthand for "in bijection with a set of natural numbers." And for the **third time**, I **still** don't see how this has anything to do with the question! If you have problems with the argument I've outlined above, I'd be happy to help; but I really don't see how this is productive.

Comment: @Noah Schweber I don't think you can fruitfully contribute to the discussion when you couldn't (as you seem to have not been able to) recognize a circular definition when you see it .

Comment: @NamNguyen **It is not a circular definition** (unless, like "countable," you're defining "circular" differently from the rest of us). Let me put it this way: if I use "Fleen" to mean "the same color as my hair," then surely we agree that my hair is Fleen, right? This isn't circular at all. It *relies* on already taking something (for Fleen, my hair; for countability, $\mathbb{N}$) for granted; but since that thing isn't defined in terms of Fleen/countability, we're fine.

Comment: And, **fourth time now**: What does this have to do with your question? This is the last off-topic comment I'll respond to (especially since you seem to be more interested in scoring points and insulting me than actually understanding mathematics).

Comment: @Noah Schweber It actually does: it's a distinct possibility that as a matter of mathematical reasoning/logic, even if the Goldbach Conjecture is false, it could still be impossible to verify it so even in principle, contrary to what mainstream mathematics might have **assumed**, thus making the original question "Can the Goldbach Conjecture be an impossible-to-prove statement, if true?" a meaningful one, as far as the foundation of mathematics is concerned.

Comment: @NamNguyen OK, this is on topic, but it's wrong: if Goldbach is false, then it is disprovable. By the way, I never argued that the original question was meaningless, just that at present we can't answer it. I'm curious: **why** do you think that Goldbach could be un-disprovably false? What part of the argument above do you disagree with?

Comment: @Noah Schweber We know from FOL inference rules , given a unary predicate P(x), we'd have P(c) -> ExP(x), where c is an individual constant symbol of the language. However in general we can't have the other way around: ExP(x) -> P(c).

So, if P(x) <-> cGC(x), and cGC(x) <-> "x is a counter example of the Golbach Conjecture", it's logically natural to ask if ExcGC(x) is true, we can find a constant c = SSSS...S0 at all! The mainstream mathematics would say yes, but the seemingly circular definition of the set of the natural numbers being countable would stand in the way of convincing, imho.

Comment: @NamNguyen Oh, I understand your confusion now (I think). From $T\vdash \exists xP(x)$ we cannot conclude that there is some term $c$ such that $T\vdash P(c)$; this is true. Here $T$ is a first-order *theory*. However, for a *structure*, the situation may be different, and indeed for the natural numbers it is: if $\mathbb{N}\models \exists x\varphi(x)$, then $\mathbb{N}\models \varphi(c)$ for some term $c$. (cont'd)

Comment: Of course, this relies on "having" the natural numbers as a well-defined thing; and you can argue that there is some weirdness here (not circularity, so much as taking certain things axiomatically, e.g. the existence of inductive sets). There are a number of questions on math.stackexchange and mathoverflow about perceived circularity in the definition of N. But this is a different question from what you asked. And note that if we are being Platonist about things, then $\mathbb{N}$ simply exists and there is no difficulty; and formalistically, everything above is provable in ZFC (or weaker).

Comment: If you are "weakly Platonist" - that is, believe in mathematical existence, but not necessarily in $\mathbb{N}$ - this boils down to: do you believe that there is a set $X$ with an element $0$ and a binary relation $<$ such that $X$ satisfies induction? If so, then such an $X$ is effectively the natural numbers (an important point of non-circularity: we can prove that any two such structures are isomorphic), and we can show by induction that $X$ has the "witness property" that we described above. If not, then you do not believe that even PA (say) is "true", so things get weird.

Comment: However, note that verifying that $n$ is a counterexample to Goldbach takes small-degree-polynomial-in-$n$-many steps, so I think even ultrafinitists would agree that, to the extent to which Goldbach is meaningful, if it is undisprovable in PA then it is true.

Comment: Regardless, this winds up being a very different question than the one you ask. If you are interested in foundational issues around defining $\mathbb{N}$, look at some of the questions on this site; if they don't satisfy you, ask your own. But this question, as posed, has been answered. (Also, side note: we never use "countable" in the definition of $\mathbb{N}$. Look up the definition of the natural numbers in ZFC, for example. I suspect some of your confusion comes from mixing different sources, which are informal in different and conflicting ways (a common issue).)

Comment: Would it be too much to ask you to stop asserting your opponent has confusion while you can't present concrete facts to prove your assertion?

Comment: I have presented **many** concrete facts, and it has taken much pushing and prodding to get you to make *any* meaningful statement. If someone else wants to help you, they can; I'm done here.

Comment: Well then you're the one who is very much confused on the issue.  And I'm very much done with this dialog.

Comment: You said that most mathematicians believe it is very unlikely for the Goldbach conjecture to be decidable in $PA$. Which mathematicians believe so? Just curious.